# Filter content of ComboBox

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm tring to filter the content of a ComboBox at runtime depending on the selected Value of another ComoboBox, but somehow my filter code does not work.

In words:

1. I get the control byID.
2. I get the Binding of the aggregation "items"
3. Create a filter
4. push the filter to the binding
5. call filter.

But nothing happens, here the sample code:

```
var oComboBoxControl = this.getView().byId(someID);

var oBindingComboBox = oComboBoxControl.getBinding("items");

var aFiltersComboBox = [];
var oFilterPComboBox = new sap.ui.model.Filter("SomeAttribute", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, 'SOMESTRING');
aFiltersComboBox.push(oFilterComboBox);
oBindingComboBox.filter(aFiltersComboBox);
```

I used the same code on tables and it works like a charm. I don't get the problem. Is it a general problem with ComboBox

The problem is with a standalone ComboBox in the view the code works, but the combobox is embedded into a List structure with multiple occurences of this comboBox.

I think I'm doing something wrong in getting the related ID of the combobox.

```
var sSOMEID = oEvent.oSource.getParent().getParent().getParent().getItems()[1].getItems()[0].getCustomControl().getId();
```

Is that the right approach for dynamic generated control ids to get them ? Not sure.

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="sap.m.sample.CustomListItem.List"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns="sap.m">
    <List headerText="Custom Content" mode="Delete" items="{path: '/SomeSet'}" >
        <CustomListItem>
            <HBox>
                <core:Icon size="2rem" src="sap-icon://attachment-photo" class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom" />
                <VBox  class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom" >
                    <ComboBox id="idSomeComboBox"
                     items="{
                     path: '/SomeSet', templateShareable: true,
                     sorter: { path: 'Description' }
                     }"
                     >
                     <core:Item key="{ID}"
                     text="{Description}"/>
                     </ComboBox>
                </VBox>
            </HBox>
        </CustomListItem>
    </List>
</mvc:View>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not setting the filter to the correct combo box:

You retrieve the `ComboBox` in `var oComboBoxControl`, but get the binding from `oProductGroupControl`, and never use `oComboBoxControl` later on.

Your code now looks fine... I tried it in an event handler (text input change filters the `ComboBox`) and it works as expected.

```
doFilter : function(oEvent) {
    var filter = oEvent.getParameter("newValue");

    var oComboBoxControl = this.getView().byId("cb");

    var oBindingComboBox = oComboBoxControl.getBinding("items");

    var aFiltersComboBox = [];
    var oFilterComboBox = new sap.ui.model.Filter("text", "Contains", filter);
    aFiltersComboBox.push(oFilterComboBox);
    oBindingComboBox.filter(aFiltersComboBox);
}
```

A few thoughts:

- Can you check the code is actually executed?
- You're using a filter that checks for equality; the specified filter should therefore match the content exactly. Can you try with `Contains` instead of `EQ`?

Comment: Thanks fixed that , was a copy paste error.Posted some additional some information above.

Comment: Thanks but that is not the solution, The Combobox which I'm trying to access is part of a List Control.

Comment: Ah... in that case, I believe you've hit the same wall as I did I guess; see my issue on GitHub https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/130#issuecomment-225539283 from 2 years ago.... :-/

Comment: Not exactly the same, but the same direction of creating dynamic filters

Answer (score 0):

You can use the loaditems method:

```
<ComboBox id="idSomeComboBox" loadItems="handleLoadItems" ...

handleLoadItems: function (oControlEvent) {
        var oModelInt = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("data");
        var oDataInt = oModelInt.getData();
        var sValue = oDataInt.value;
        var oFilter1 = new sap.ui.model.Filter('text', sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, sValue);
        var filters = [oFilter1];
        oControlEvent.getSource().getBinding("items").filter(filters, sap.ui.model.FilterType.Application);
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).